# Flutter Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@1ca92971

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-launcher-icons

I got this error after using flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.13.1

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
C:\Users\SEiS\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\17c44a9ee9728471e88635da67cac57c\transformed\core-1.10.1\res\values\values.xml:7:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 64 in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
C:\Users\SEiS\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\17c44a9ee9728471e88635da67cac57c\transformed\core-1.10.1\res\values\values.xml:7:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```